# Secure way of providing MySQL password in a batch file

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We have a batch file that, among other things, performs some database operations.  To keep things non-interactive, currently we pass the DB user id and password information on the command line.  We keep getting the following warning messages:
`Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.`

Kindly suggest how to pass the DB password information to the batch file so that it remains non-interactive and yet secure.

Comment: What Operating System is this? "Batch" files (.bat) are Windows-based, but batch can be a generic term as well?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68131331

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard method is to use an additional configuration file that contains the password and reference *that* on the command-line.

See this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827340/protect-the-password-when-using-mysql-in-an-unattended-bash-script).

Comment: `mysql --defaults-extra-file my-extra-options.ini -h <host> <database> -e <query>` appears to be a good option.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what operating system you are using. "Batch" files are typically associated with .bat Windows files, but the term can be generic as well...

But if you're talking about Windows .bat files, then .bat files have no built-in way to securely handle passwords.

Take a look at [this Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59432807/is-there-a-way-to-store-and-retrieve-a-password-in-a-file-from-a-batch-script) answer that details how to handle secure credentials in PowerShell. It has al the steps you need, though it will require converting your .bat files to PowerShell scripts or calling PowerShell from within the .bat file.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use mysql_config_editor with suitable parameters.

(This works for Docker, too.)

```
mysql_config_editor set -G m10307 -P 10307 -u root -p -h `hostname`
# -P overides port (default is 3306)
# -p prompts for the password
# `hostname` could be replaced by some remote hostname

# Invoke via the name given by `-G`:
mysql --login-path=m10307
```

This is probably better than an extra config file because this is encrypted.

I suspect the OS "user" running the script and the "user" invoking `mysql_config_editor` must be the same -- since the encrypted info is stored as that "user":

```
-rw-------  1 rj rj   2168 May 24 12:49 .mylogin.cnf
```